# AsyncTask causa um erro fatal durante a execução do método doInBackground()

Tags: android, asynctask

O código não apresenta nenhum erro, porém quando vou executar, ele pára e apresenta um erro Fatal em tempo de execução na classe AsyncLoadXMLFeed que extende de AsyncTask.

segue o código da class AsyncLoadXMLFeed que esta dentro da SplashActivity

```
public class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public AsyncLoadXMLFeed() {

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Obtem o feed
        DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
        feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
        if(feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0)
            WriteFeed(feed);            
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        startLisActivity(feed);
    }

}

private void WriteFeed(RSSFeed data) {

    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    ObjectOutputStream osw = null;

    try {
        fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
        osw.writeObject(data);
        osw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Apenas dizer que dá erro e não dizer qual é, não ajuda quem te possa querer ajudar.

Comment: Concordo com o @ramaral, seria bom dar uma olhada no logcat pra ver se não tem nenhum stacktrace do erro que ocorreu.

Answer (score -1):

Galera, descobrir o erro.

Tinha uma biblioteca que eu fazia referencia a ela, mas o arquivo jar não estava na pasta bin. Ai quando era compilado o projeto a biblioteca não era empacotada no apk. Dai dava o erro.

Solução: foi copiar na mão grande o arquivo para a pasta bin e dar um refresh nela e depois um clear e refresh no projeto todo.

Valeu!!!